# How to scale up layout on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone-6-plus

I have enabled launch screen in my project, but I find the login view is quite small as it's still using iPhone 5 layout constraints. Is there any simple way to scale up the view on iPhone 6 plus?
[image]

Comment: can you provide your constraints?

Answer (score 1):

When i was confronted with the same problem i started to use autoAutoLayout, works perfectly.

https://github.com/cathyxchen/autoAutoLayout

**Example**

Just build your Interface in the Interface Builder or create it programmatically. Then create NO constraints, just place the controls where you want them.

After that just place

`[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
 [AutoAutoLayout layoutFromBaseModel:@"5" forSubviewsOf:self.view];`

in your ViewController.m. (I placed it in the viewDidLoad Method)

Now it calculates the positions of the controls based on the BaseModel (in my Case iPhone5) to all other iPhone Display sizes.

**Code Description**

`[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];`

This deletes all constraints, just to be sure there are no hidden and overseen ones.

`[AutoAutoLayout layoutFromBaseModel:@"5" forSubviewsOf:self.view];`

This calls the Method to recalculate the new positions from the BaseModel.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you're using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the scale solve method by Autolayout, please see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html